# Forcing a copy with a Thor action

Tags: ruby, thor

I'm using the Thor built-in action "copy_file" to copy a file from my template source, overwriting an existing file.

I always want to overwrite, and don't want to have to confirm this interactively.

The documentation doesn't suggest there is a force option in the config hash for this action, but http://textmate.rubyforge.org/thor/Thor/Actions.html does indicate that config[:behavior] can be set to force, but I can't see how to do this.

If anyone has an example of doing this that they could share, I'd be most grateful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the source of `copy_file` action at https://github.com/erikhuda/thor/blob/master/lib/thor/actions/file_manipulation.rb it uses `create_file` and passes config Hash to it. Ok, let us see specs for create_file  https://github.com/erikhuda/thor/blob/master/spec/actions/create_file_spec.rb . Search the file for 'force', action can be invoked with:

```
create_file("doc/config.rb", :force => true)
```

Try that with your `copy_file` action, append `:force => true` at the end, it is treated as config hash, passed to create_file and it should work.